# sliding panel from left to right side

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a panel and its positioned in the left side I tried to reposition it from the left to the right side can anyone me here my [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v58eozu1) thank you.

here is the mark up and my js

```js
$(function(){
 $(document).on('click','.slider-arrow.show',function(){
     $( ".slider-arrow, .panel" ).animate({
          left: "+=300"
    }, 700, function() {
            // Animation complete.
          });
    $(this).html('&laquo;').removeClass('show').addClass('hide');
    });
 
 $(document).on('click','.slider-arrow.hide',function(){
     $( ".slider-arrow, .panel" ).animate({
          left: "-=300"
    }, 700, function() {
            // Animation complete.
          });
    $(this).html('&raquo;').removeClass('hide').addClass('show');
    });
});
```

```css
.panel {
 width:300px;
 float:left;
 height:550px;
 background:#d9dada;
 position:relative;
 left:-300px;

}
.slider-arrow {
 padding:5px;
 width:10px;
 float:left;
 background:#d9dada;
 font:400 12px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 color:#000;
 text-decoration:none;
 position:relative;
 left:-300px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="panel">
      </div>
      
      <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="slider-arrow show">&raquo;</a>
```

Comment: What if someone has JavaScript disabled?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's mostly just changing `left` to `right` with your `float` and `left` position attributes. There are better ways to approach this problem, generally using `position: absolute`, but this works too.

```
body {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Will prevent there from being a horizontal scrollbar on the page.

https://jsfiddle.net/v58eozu1/2/